# Test Django admin form

Tags: python, django, forms, admin

I'd like to test adding a custom document file form in my application in the admin panel. Unfortunately django documentation is quite obscure about this one.

This is my model:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    pdf_doc = models.FileField(upload_to=repo_dir, max_length=255)
```

This is my test:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test import Client
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class DocumentAdminFormTest(TestCase):

    def test_add_document_form(self):
        client = Client()
        change_url = 'admin/docrepo/document/add/'
        today = datetime.today()
        filepath = u'/filepath/to/some/pdf/'
        data = {'title': 'TEST TITLE',
                'description': 'TEST DESCRIPTION', 
                'pub_date0': '2000-01-01',
                'pub_date1': '00:00:00',
                'pdf_doc': filepath,
                }
        response = client.post(change_url, data)
        print('REASON PHRASE: ' + response.reason_phrase)
        self.assertIs(response.status_code, 200)
```

I'd like to get 200 response while posting the form with shown data. For some reason response.status_code gives 404 and response.reason_phrase gives 'Not Found'. Is it possible the problem lies in the directory?

Comment: Usually the URL starts with a slash.

Comment: Ok, that pushed me a bit further ... now response.status_code  returns 304 and response.reason_phrase gives 'Found'.

Is it possible it's because of lacking login step?

Answer (score 6):

You have to [log the client in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login):

```
c = Client()
c.login(username='your_username', password='your_password')
response = c.post(change_url, data)
```

The most correct way to define `change_url` is using `reverse()`. You can [browse the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-reverse-urls) to find the correct way to do this. For example:

```
change_url = reverse('admin:docrepo_document_add')
```